# scrollable tabs custom user Interface

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-studio-2.0, android-scrollable-tabs

I am working on a Scrollable tabs and came to observe a custom scrollable tabe in a mediaplayer app but  don't know what is used in this as per my knowledge it is like scrollable tabs.Any hint how to achieve this while changing from one fragment to another .I want to show a gape in the fragment while scrolling as in this app?THIS is what I created
[image]
this is what i want a gape between two fragment
[image]

I tried to give padding in the view pager but it is not working at all.
my layout content main .xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/pager"
android:background="@drawable/gradient2"
>
<android.support.v4.view.PagerTitleStrip
android:id="@+id/title"
style="@style/viewPagerTitleStrip"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="40dp"
android:layout_gravity="top"
android:paddingTop="4dp"
android:paddingBottom="4dp"
android:background="@drawable/gradient1">

</android.support.v4.view.PagerTitleStrip>
</android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
```

I tried both padding and margine in the ViewPager but it is not working

Comment: try margins instead of padding for your fragments

Comment: tried its not working can u tell me some other way or any tutorials ,or any hint

Comment: Is my question valid??

Comment: the question seems valid to me. you had a specific bug and you showed us what you wanted. (I didn't downvote you).  you can also edit your  question to show us your codes and xml for us to help you better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the similar property used try this https://github.com/astuetz/PagerSlidingTabStrip

Since I am using ViewPager, the easiest way to achieve some space is to use the `setPageMargin()` method of Viewpager, which in my case will be

```
ViewPager pager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
pager.setPageMargin(200);
//200 is value in pixel
```

There is also a method `setPageMarginDrawable()` sets a drawable that will be used to fill the margin between pages (Android documentation).